# UPDATED: Could it be an issue to deploy Gnosis Safe contracts on a gas less chain?

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis

I have a private side chain which is a fork of Ethereum but without gas fees.

I want to install the full Gnosis Architecture on that chain.
I managed to run everything correctly (I think).
Now Im trying to interact with the safes.

I can create a safe (GnosisSafe.sol) but I cant send funds to it. the transaction is reverted with unknown reason.

Although I can create a safe l2 (GnosisSafeL2.sol by changing the "l2" option in the config service db) which i can send funds to, BUT i cannot transfer out the tokens once they are there...  the transaction is also reverted with unknown reason.

Do you have any idea what could cause this ?
thanks a lot in advance

**UPDATE**
FYI, the chain is on Petersburg hardfork.

**UPDATE**:
I introduced some gas but i get the same error so i guess thats not the issue.
here are some info on the transaction (it's a ERC20 transfer out of the safe).

maybe someone can see that something is wrong there

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was was the version of the blockchain. I was on Petersburg and the minimum version required (not in the documentation though) is Istambul.